# Materialize's select bottom line can not be disable

Tags: css, select, border, materialize, underline

Anybody knows how to disable de materialize's select underline. It seems to be an border, but it's not. I try to disable with `'border: none'` also tried with `:before` but none of them works for me. This is the line I want to disable:

[image: is the grey one]

please help.

Comment: It seems to be under the input, with a border-bottom of 1px solid #9e9e9e, changing to none should work.

Comment: Please translate this to English.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

`.select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
    border-bottom: none;
}`